# Add item numbers to items in Magento Invoice PDF

Tags: magento, pdf, invoice

I am trying to do something that should be really simple, but I am stuck.

I am trying to add serial numbers (1,2,3 etc) to the items in Magento's invoice pdf under a column called Serial Number.

Any clues on how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This two files are responsible for displaying invoice pdf content
app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\Default.php
app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php
Overwrite this two files or simply just put in your local folder

Now add Serial number header in this file app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php
you can fin `_drawHeader` function just add something like this before products column

```
$lines[0][] = array(
        'text' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Serial number'),
        'feed' => 35
    );
```

Now go to app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\Default.php this file you can find `draw()` function

From `$this->getItem();` you can find item count and put your for loop here for displaying serial numbers something like

```
for($j=1; $j<=count($this->getItem());$j++)
{
 $lines[$j][] = array(
                'text'  => $j,
                'font'  => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right'
            );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this. but I get an error:'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'' on the line 'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->($i, 35, true, true),

Comment: No, this does not work either. It repeats the number '1' and adds it to a new line. So it is 1, 1, 1 etc. with each serial number on a line of its own.

Comment: invoice.php -> link -> paste.ofcode.org/3gHXE4bMUVdzXLBKtx6uQH  default.php -> link -> paste.ofcode.org/bmNig6Lj2Lnb82DrcmD3MF still serial number not adding in my invoice. May i know my workout right? @Mufaddal

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the steps**

---

Step 1: You have to work with two files of core mage, so, copy that files with their respective folder structure. and paste in to local directory. that both files are as follows:

From :
(1) app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php
(2) app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\Default.php

To :
(1) app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php
(2) app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\Default.php

(NOTE: Please, copy both above files in to local directory with respective folder structure rather than change directly in to core files.)

Step 2: Now, first work with Invoice.php file.

Paste the following code before product name add header code.

```
//Serial Number
$lines[0][] = array(
‘text’ => Mage::helper(‘sales’)->__(‘#’),
‘feed’ => 35
);
```

And Change feed value of Product column as following :

```
$lines[0][] = array(
‘text’ => Mage::helper(‘sales’)->__(‘Products’),
‘feed’ => 70
);
```

So it will looks like following :

```
/* Add table head */
$this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
$page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
$page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
$page->setLineWidth(0.5);
$page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y -15);
$this->y -= 10;
$page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));

//columns headers

//Serial Number
$lines[0][] = array(
‘text’ => Mage::helper(‘sales’)->__(‘#’),
‘feed’ => 35
);

$lines[0][] = array(
‘text’ => Mage::helper(‘sales’)->__(‘Products’),
‘feed’ => 70
);
```

Step 3: Now, remaining work with Default.php file.

Paste the following code after product name printing code and after the $lines array declaration.

```
$var_srno = Mage::registry(‘sr_no’);
if($var_srno!=0)
{
$new_sr = $var_srno + 1;
$sr_no = $new_sr;
Mage::unregister(‘sr_no’);
}
else{
$new_sr = 1;
}
Mage::register(‘sr_no’, $new_sr);

$lines[0][] = array(
‘text’ => $new_sr,
‘feed’ => 35
);
```

and now also change the code of $lines[0][] for getting item name as follows:

```
$lines[0][] = array(
‘text’ => Mage::helper(‘core/string’)->str_split($item->getName(), 70, true, true),
‘feed’ => 70,
);
```

so, now, it will looks like the following:

```
$order  = $this->getOrder();
    $item   = $this->getItem();
    $pdf    = $this->getPdf();
    $page   = $this->getPage();
    $lines  = array();

    // draw Product name
    $lines[0] = array(array(
        'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($item->getName(), 35, true, true),
        'feed' => 70
    ));

    $var_srno = Mage::registry('sr_no');
    if($var_srno!=0)
    {
        $new_sr = $var_srno + 1;
        $sr_no = $new_sr;
        Mage::unregister('sr_no');
    }
    else{
        $new_sr = 1;
    }
    Mage::register('sr_no', $new_sr);

    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text' => $new_sr,
        'feed' => 35
    );

    // draw SKU
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($this->getSku($item), 17),
        'feed'  => 190,
        'align' => 'right'
    );
```

Step 4: Save both files and Clear Magento Cache. and See the result.